# How to pass runtime arguments to a viewmodel?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mvvm, dagger-hilt

I have a viewmodel that looks like this:

```
 class FilterByCategoryViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    private val dataManager: AppDataManager,
    private val networkHelper: NetworkHelper,
    private val category: String
) : ViewModel() { ...
 }
```

I will get `dataManager` and `networkHelper` from the `ApplicationModule`. But I need to pass `category` as a runtime parameter. I tried the below approach but I got the error Could not resolve `AssistedModule`.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65375442/5742365

I have also tried creating a viewmodel factory as below:

```
val factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory = object : ViewModelProvider.Factory() {
                @NonNull
                override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(@NonNull modelClass: Class<T>): T {
                    return FilterByCategoryViewModel(
                        category
                    ) as T
                }
            }
filterByCategoryViewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity(), factory).get(FilterByCategoryViewModel::class.java)
```

But then I had to edit the viewmodel to have the `category` parameter in the constructor and the `networkHelper` and `dataManager` parameters injected using field injection (I'm not sure whether it works that way or not). But it still didn't work. The Viewmodel now looks as follows:

```
    class FilterByCategoryViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
        private val category: String
    ) : ViewModel() {
        @Inject
        lateinit var dataManager: AppDataManager
        @Inject
        lateinit var networkHelper: NetworkHelper
...
}
```

Now I get this build error when I run the app:

```
D:\Workspace\AndroidProjects\RecipeApp\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\neeraja\recipeapp\ui\viewmodel\FilterByCategoryViewModel.java:20: error: incompatible types: NonExistentClass cannot be converted to Annotation
    @error.NonExistentClass()
          ^D:\Workspace\AndroidProjects\RecipeApp\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\neeraja\recipeapp\ui\viewmodel\FilterByCategoryViewModel.java:34: error: incompatible types: NonExistentClass cannot be converted to Annotation
    @error.NonExistentClass()
          ^
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and support-compat-26.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
     Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and support-compat-26.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
     Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and support-compat-26.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
     Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and support-compat-26.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
     Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and support-compat-26.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
     Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub$Proxy found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and support-compat-26.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
     Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and support-compat-26.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
     Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$1 found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and support-compat-26.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
     Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and support-compat-26.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
     Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and support-compat-26.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
     
     Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
```

I'm learning Hilt, MVVM, Kotlin by myself and feel so stuck with this. Any suggestions on achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally used ViewModelProvider.Factory as follows:

```
class FilterByTypeViewModelFactory constructor(val dataManager: AppDataManager, 
                                               val networkHelper: NetworkHelper, 
                                               val category: String) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return FilterByCategoryViewModel(dataManager , networkHelper , category) as T
    }
}
```

The ViewModel now looks as follows:

```
class FilterByCategoryViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    val dataManager: AppDataManager,
    val networkHelper: NetworkHelper,
    val category: String
) : ViewModel() {
...
}
```

And in the Fragment:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class FilterByTypeFragment : Fragment() {
    @Inject lateinit var dataManager: AppDataManager
    @Inject lateinit var networkHelper: NetworkHelper
    ...
     override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        if (arguments != null) {
            category = arguments?.get("categoryId") as String
            val factory = FilterByTypeViewModelFactory(dataManager, networkHelper, category)
            filterByCategoryViewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity(), factory).get(FilterByCategoryViewModel::class.java)
        }
        setupUI()
        setupObserver()
    }
...
}
```

This is working for me. I have just been learning hilt. I was confused with the options like using ViewModelProvider.Factory or AssistedInject. Although this solution worked for me, I would like to know more about AssistedInject and the situations where we need to choose one over the other.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about hilt, but I have done this same thing with Dagger2 using **AssistedInject**.
Here is my implementation,

```
class MyViewModel @AssistedInject constructor(
    @Assisted private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
    dataSource: RemoteDataSource 
) : ViewModel() {

    @AssistedInject.Factory
    interface Factory : AssistedSavedStateViewModelFactory<MyViewModel> {
        override fun create(savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle): MyViewModel
    }    
    val groupId = savedStateHandle.getLiveData("groupId", "")
    val searchType = savedStateHandle.getLiveData("searchType", 1)
    }
```

In fragment/activit

```
val defArgs = bundleOf("groupId" to groupId, "searchType" to searchType)        
val factory = viewModelFactory.create(this, defArgs)
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, factory)[MyViewModel::class.java]
```

Comment: Now I keep getting `FilterByCategoryViewModel.Factory cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method` error when I rebuild the project

Comment: I have added a Module as follows to avoid the error:
@AssistedModule
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
interface AssistedInjectModule {}

Now I keep getting `AssistedInjectModule is missing an @InstallIn annotation even though I have kept @InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)`